# Best way to provide help content along with a .xla add-in

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, xla

I am about to deploy an excel addin (.xla) for coworkers to use (Office 2007).

Is there a way to embed a help file somewhere?

**UPDATE**

I've made it by including the .PDF file as an Object embedded in 'This_Workbook'. I could trigger its opening using VBA and when I saved the .xlsm file as .xlam the .pdf become 'hidden' in there.

This way there was no need to give separated files and I think its easy this way.

Comment: [Workbook_Open](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/auto-run-macros.htm) event could trigger an [UserForm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853685/how-to-create-an-user-interface-userform-in-excel-vba/16854404#16854404) which would display a *Welcome/Help* message

Comment: I was thinking about opening a .pdf file and the question is how to make it go along within a single file (.xla). Any ideas?

Comment: trigger/open the pdf at the workbook open or add a control to ribbon with a tiny help icon and an event procedure?

Comment: @mehow, is there a way to hide the .pdf inside the workbook?

Comment: i dont think there is. but you can write a file with vba. or use an external library to do that. do once workbook opens or a macro executes it would trigger the writing of a file

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the correct way to do this is using a `.chm` file. You include it in the same folder as your `.xla` and access it with VBA as follows:

```
Application.Help ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Somefile.chm", contextID
```

See the options provided at MSDN: [Displaying Help from VBA Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140546%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

Personally, I didn't like any of the options, so I just give a PDF to whoever needs to use my Add-ins.